# Linked Server Query of Encrypted Data with Symmetric Key/Certificate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I suppose if I had to really boil it down to one thing, the real question is: "*Is there a way to use some sort of 4-part identifier syntax-equivalent to call a keyand certificate AND keep it open so that a 4-part identifier `SELECT` statement can utilize it **using a linked server**?*"

---

All the servers are **SQL Server 2012**.

When I log on to the server (`SERVER_A`) in SSMS (this server has the encrypted data), I can simply `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY` and `DECRYPTION WITH` the certificate, then wrap the columns with `DECRYPTWITHKEY` and be on my way.

**SERVER_A query in SSMS:**

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [KEY]
DECRYPTION WITH [CERTIFICATE]
GO

SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DECRYPTWITHKEY(col)) AS ColA
FROM
    SCHEMA.TABLE
GO
```

I have another server (`SERVER_B`) with a linked server connection to `SERVER_A`.  From `SERVER_B`, I would like to be able to do a similar thing syntactically, but I'm not having any luck.

I was successful in using the `EXEC [SERVER_A].DATABASE.dbo.sp_executesql N'<above code>'` with `RPC` turned on, but this method requires escaping apostrophes and I lose the IntelliSense and overall maintainability/readability of the code (which is more complex obviously than the example above).

Is there a way to do something akin to the following:

***Ideal* SERVER_B query "form" in SSMS:**

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [SERVER_A].DATABASE.[KEY]
DECRYPTION WITH [SERVER_A].DATABASE.[CERTIFICATE]
GO

SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DECRYPTWITHKEY(col)) AS ColA
FROM
    [SERVER_A].DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE
GO
```

Or at a minimum, keep the key open so that I can use the 4-part identifier syntax `SELECT` statement (i.e. without wrapping the entire thing in an `OPENQUERY` which I have done and works, but I don't want to have to quote the whole query)?  For better or for worse practice/performance, the actual `SELECT` statement calls data from 3 different servers on the intranet, so that 4-part identifier syntax is very convenient, readability-wise.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but just came across the same scenario and got this working by using below query, using [OPENQUERY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188427.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY( [SERVER_A], '
            EXEC ('' USE [DATABASE];

                    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [KEY]
                    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [CERTIFICATE]

                    SELECT
                        CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DECRYPTWITHKEY(col)) AS ColA
                    FROM
                        SCHEMA.TABLE
                '') 
                ')
```

Comment: "(i.e. without wrapping the entire thing in an OPENQUERY which I have done and works, but I don't want to have to quote the whole query)"

Answer (score 0):

For query that requires parameter the following worked for me -

```
declare @param nvarchar(20)
set @param = 'param value'
declare @qSQL nvarchar(1000)
SET @qSQL = '
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
    OPENQUERY([Linked_Server],''        
        EXEC ('''' USE [Database_Name];

                open symmetric key key_name
                decryption by certificate cert_name;

                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    [Table_Name]
                where CONVERT(varchar(Max), DECRYPTBYKEY(Column_Name))) = '''''''''+@param+'''''''''
            '''') 
    '');';

EXEC sp_executesql @qSQL;
```